# Walklist Splitting by Street and Odd/Even

Tags: civicampaign

In the configuration for CiviEngage, I have selected options to have a group break between each street and between evens and odds, and then for there to be a page break between groups.

How do I generate a walk list that follows these rules? When I go to Campaigns > Campaign Reports and then print a report from the Survey I want, it gives me a list that's organized properly - by street alphabetically and then by odds/evens - but with no page breaks. The page breaks are critical, of course, to organizing the walk list in a way that makes geographic sense.

Comment: Oh yeah, the other issue, while I'm at it, is that I need for the walk list to include the Supplementary Address field (i.e. apartment number).

When I go into the report options I can have it include this, but it doesn't produce a report that can be used as a walk list - doesn't have the responses for the different questions to mark.

And, when I just do a Print Report as mentioned above, it just goes with a default that doesn't include apartment numbers, but is laid out like a walk list with the responses.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I worked it out for myself! Posting the answers here in case someone else runs into the same issue. The fundamental problem is that the location of Create Templates From Reports has changed from when the CiviCRM User Guide was created.

So now it's Administer > CiviReport > Create New Report From Template

Once there, you go to Survey Report (Detail) which should be at the bottom.

Then, select the columns you want displayed, and then in sorting select how you want it sorted -- Street Name, Ascending and Odd/Even Street Number, Ascending.

Then, on that same screen, check the Section Heading/Group By and Page Break boxes to the right of Street Name but NOT for Odd/Even (at least for me, grouping by odd/even did weird things).

The last bit of setup is under Filters, set "Survey" to the specific Survey you've set up, and "Respondent Status" is equal to Reserved.

The final step is you have to export to PDF if you want it broken up by page, as Print Report just gives you a single run of text. Ultimately it looks like the CiviEngage settings I mentioned int he OP don't do much for you.

Hope this is helpful to anyone else who's been perplexed by the User Guide not matching up to what you're seeing in your CiviCRM! If anyone else more experienced has anything to add, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer!  You can [submit changes](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide) to the User Guide to help others - but if that's too much work/too technical, please reply to this comment with a link to the page that has the bad instructions and I'll fix it.